# Is any episode of the Netlifx's "Love, Death & Robots" part of a bigger series?

Tags: love-death-and-robots

Netflix recently released the first season of a (very) adult animation series called *Love, Death & Robots*. Each 15 minute episode is independent and completely unrelated to others, each one is made in a different style - from lifelike CGI to the simplest cartoons.

I am just wondering, are any of the episodes part of a bigger series presented in books, movies etc?

The list of episodes can be [found on IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9561862/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1).

Comment: I wish that "Lucky 13" one was. That was *awesome*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least one is - the first episode ["Sonnie's Edge"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9781722/?ref_=ttep_ep1) is based on a short story by Peter F. Hamilton, in his 1998 collection *A Second Chance at Eden*.

All the stories in that collection are set at various points in the history of the Confederation, the political entity that governs humanity in Hamilton's [*Night's Dawn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night%27s_Dawn_Trilogy) universe. The bulk of this story plays out in the Night's Dawn trilogy, beginning with [*The Reality Dysfunction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reality_Dysfunction).

Comment: I thought that one seemed familiar! Thanks!